# Get latest commit of list of files with Git

Tags: git, shell

I'm trying to retrieve the most recent commit who modified/edited a list of files I provide.

In practice, if I have `a.txt` and `b.txt`, where `a.txt` has been modified yesterday and `b.txt` has been modified 2 hours ago, I want to get the latest commit which edited `b.txt`.

This is my script so far:

```
for file in components/*/index.jsx
do
  # 1. Get the dirname of the current file
  dir=`dirname $file`
  # 2. Get a space separated list of files to check in $dir
  files=`find $dir -type f | grep -E -v "demo.jsx|.test.jsx|meta.json|__snapshots__" | tr '\n' ' '`
  # 3. Get the most recent commit that touched any of the listed files
  commit=`git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H -- $files | cat`
  # 4. Get the version of the package.json at the specific $commit
  version=`git show $commit:packages/react-components/package.json | cat | grep -m 1 version`
  # 5. Insert the version in the meta.json of the component
  sed -i'' -e "2s/.*/$version/" $dir/meta.json
  # 6. Remove the backup file generated by sed
  rm $dir/meta.json-e
done
```

The problem is in step #3, it doesn't return any commit at all if I provide multiple files.

This is the log of the problematic step:

```
❯ echo $files
components/Foobar/index.jsx components/Foobar/index.sss 

❯ git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H -- $files | cat
# nothing
```

If instead I run:

```
❯ git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H -- components/Foobar/index.jsx components/Foobar/index.sss | cat
93012738e776f4ffe920161ba61501ed84b815a5
```

I get the commit hash...

Ideas?

**update**:
If I run:

```
`echo "git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H -- $files"`
```

it prints the commit hash, why?

Comment: Step 3 looks fine, try running your script using `bash -x $script_name` to see the commands that are executed.

Comment: Have you tried running `git log -- <list of files>` manually? If this works (it should), then I think the problem lies in generating `$files`.

Comment: Also, if I'm not mistaken, piping into `cat` is pretty much useless.

Comment: I added some info in the question. `cat` is needed to print to stdout

Comment: Where do you think the output of `git log` goes without `cat`!? Have you tried leaving `| cat` away?

Comment: It opens vim (or something pretty similar?)

Comment: I see. But it should only do that in "interactive" use, not when redirecting the output into a variable or some other command.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  By the way, that's not the problem AFAIK

Comment: As a general rule, if `| cat` affects a command's behavior, the command in question is probably checking whether stdout is a tty. `prog | cat` is writing to a pipe, not a tty; `prog` is writing to a tty. However, in a script, using backquotes or dollar-paren (as in `files=$(prog)`), the output from `prog` is going to a pipe—this is a pipe that the shell reads—so again `| cat` *should* make no difference. When `prog` is `git log`, it *does* check for tty by default, to know when to use the pager. If you force it to always use your pager, though, even `| cat` won't help: use `--no-pager`.

Comment: For Git in particular, of course, you can switch from "porcelain" commands like `git log` (whose behavior depends on user configuration items such as `core.pager` and `pager.log`) to "plumbing" commands like `git rev-list` (whose behavior does not change based on user configuration settings). If you are writing general-purpose scripts, you should use these plumbing commands so that the behavior will remain predictable.

Comment: One more side note may be useful here (and we might need to know something about your OS and bash version): `git log --pretty=format:%H` directs `git log` to *not* print a trailing newline. If there is no pager (as in `git --no-pager log --pretty=format:%H`, or when piping through `cat`), the lack of a newline persists to the end; but if there *is* a pager, and the pager is `less`, `less` itself adds the missing newline. Using `--pretty=tformat:%H` or `--pretty=format:%H%n` restores the missing newline. That *should not* affect the result of `$(...)` or the equivalent with backquotes, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This extremely weird. Here are some more things to try.

Instructions:

- Run the snippets separately one at a time by inserting a snippet into your script just before step 3 and running the script.
- Copy and paste to avoid typos.
- To prevent the `for` loop from running several times and producing lots of output, temporarily replace `components/*/index.jsx` with `components/Foobar/index.jsx` (or whichever file triggers the problem).
- Don't do anything between theses test (like changing directory or running `git` commands).
- If a snippet doesn't produce the expected output, say which snippet and what the output was.
- Impatient? Try snippet 4 (which should succeed) and snippet 11 (which should fail). That's a sign that this is the right track and you should try all the steps.

Snippets:

1. Check which shell is running the script

   ```
   echo "$SHELL"
   ls -l "$SHELL"
   ```

   Expected output: `/bin/sh`, which might be a symbolic link to `bash` or `dash`. If it's a symbolic link to another shell (e.g. `zsh`), that would be a problem because other shells expand variables differently.
2. Double check that you don't have quotes (`"`) around `$files` in the original command.
3. Check that `$IFS` is sane.

   ```
   echo -n "$IFS" | xxd -p
   ```

   Expected output: `20090a` (hex for `<space><tab><newline>`).
   *(I know I've already asked you to do this, but please do it again from the script.)*
   `$IFS` controls word splitting, and would cause problems if it was a strange value.
4. Check that the files exist:

   ```
   ls components/Foobar/index.jsx components/Foobar/index.sss
   ```

   Expected output: `ls` should list the two files.
   If you get a "No such file or directory" error, check the working directory of the script at that point and the git branch that is checked out.
5. Try using the `files` variable, set to a string:

   ```
   files="components/Foobar/index.jsx components/Foobar/index.sss"
   ls $files
   ```

   Expected output: `ls` should list the two files.

   If you get an error such as

   ```
   ls: cannot access components/Foobar/index.jsx components/Foobar/index.sss: No such file or directory
   ```

   then something is wrong with your shell, because it doesn't do word splitting on unquoted variables.
6. Try running `ls` inside backticks.

   ```
   files="components/Foobar/index.jsx components/Foobar/index.sss"
   output=`ls $files`
   echo "$output"
   ```

   Expected output: The two files.
   If you get a "No such file or directory" error then your shell is broken and doesn't do variable expansion inside backticks properly.
7. Use `find` instead of a literal string:

   ```
   ls $files
   ```

   Unlike snippet 5, this snippet allows `$files` to keep its value from step 2 in your script.
   Expected output: `ls` should list the same two files as the previous snippet.
   If you get an error (no such file or directory), something is wrong with step 2 of your script. Check the value of `$files` using `echo -n "$files" | od -c` and post it.
8. Try the `git` command with literal file arguments:

   ```
   git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H -- components/Foobar/index.jsx components/Foobar/index.sss | cat
   echo # output of previous command doesn't have a trailing newline
   ```

   Expected output: The commit hash.
9. Try using the `$files` variable, set to a string:

   ```
   files="components/Foobar/index.jsx components/Foobar/index.sss"
   git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H -- $files | cat
   echo # output of previous command doesn't have a trailing newline
   ```

   Expected output: The commit hash.
10. Use `find` instead of a literal string:

    ```
    git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H -- $files | cat
    echo # output of previous command doesn't have a trailing newline
    ```

    Expected output: The commit hash.
11. Try the original command from the script:

    ```
    commit=`git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H -- $files | cat`
    echo "$commit"
    ```

    Expected output: The commit hash.

Comment: The first test says the script is running with zsh, but my script has the shebang `#!/bin/sh` on top 

Comment: By the way, running the script from an actual "file", it seems to work. The problem is only when I copy-paste the script in the terminal.

Comment: Well then, problem solved. The [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) is only significant when it is the very first line in a file and the file is run as a program (by running `path/to/script args...`). If you paste the script into a shell, or if you run a shell and specify the file as an argument (e.g. `bash path/to/script args...`), the shebang line is treated as just a regular comment and doesn't do anything.

Comment: So you should save the script in a file and run the file. If you want to run the script by pasting it into your interactive shell, either [permanently change your shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22729/where-do-i-change-my-shell) to bash or run bash temporarily using the command `bash`. Use the `exit` command or `Ctrl+D` to return to zsh. It can get confusing (especially when you also use ssh); a nice trick is to start bash using a command such as `bash; echo "exited from bash, back to zsh now"`, which will remind you where you are after you exit from bash.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as an answer, but it's mostly a workaround:

```
for file in components/*/index.jsx
do
  dir=`dirname $file`
  files=`find $dir -type f | grep -E -v "demo.jsx|meta.json|.test.jsx|__snapshots__" | tr '\n' ' '`
  # We basically print the command as string, and evaluate it with backtricks
  # Use only if you have complete control over the project structure!
  commit=`$(echo git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H -- $files) | cat`
  version=`git show $commit:packages/react-components/package.json | cat | grep -m 1 version`
  sed -i'' -e "2s/.*/$version/" $dir/meta.json
  rm $dir/meta.json-e
done
```

I don't know why this is needed, but it seems to work at least.

Comment: This workaround is extremely unsafe because specially crafted filenames could cause the script to run arbitrary shell commands. Check that (1) you are running your script with `bash` by printing `$SHELL` from your script and (2) that `$IFS` is <space><tab><newline> by running `echo -n "$IFS" | xxd -p` from your script (the output should be 20090a).